# EasyWSDL has missing dependencies

Tags: maven-2, wsdl, artifact

I am trying to add a WSDL module to my existing application, but I'm struggling to get the dependencies resolved.

According to their website, this is the correct dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.ow2.easywsdl</groupId>
<artifactId>easywsdl-wsdl</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After a search (search.maven.org), I already changed the version to 2.3 and there are a bunch of files that are downloaded into my local repository, but when running the application (with the websites demo code), I bump into this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ebmwebsourcing.easycommons.uri.UriManager
```

And I believe it has something to do with the missing artifacts :

```
com.ebmwebsourcing.easycommons:easycommons.uri:jar:1.1
com.ebmwebsourcing.easycommons:easycommons.logger:jar:1.1
```

In particular the first one. Now, I'm relatively new to using Maven... How would I go about solving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the petalslink repository. Appearantly the standard maven repository doesn't contain the easycommons dependency. The petalslink repository does.